# How to create a matrix style field in a custom plugin

Tags: plugin-development, craft4, custom

I'm building a custom plugin for Craft CMS 4 that has a form where users can add and remove a list of products.
Every product has a title and a price field.

Other fields have been created like this:

```
{{ forms.textField({
        label: "Note"|t('_receipts'),
        id: 'note',
        name: 'note',
        value: receipt.note,
        required: true,
        errors: receipt.getErrors('note'),
    }) }}
```

I can write some JS to add and remove fields.
That way a user can add more products.
But what should the names of the fields be?
Every field needs to be validated on save.

I will probably also need to create another DB table which will store all products and I guess I will need to store the references to those products in the main table.

Does anyone have any pointers on how to tackle this in the best way possible?

Comment: Welcome! Can you elaborate a little bit - you mention products but is this a craft commerce product or a data object you made that you're calling a product? What is the product in your setup (an entry? custom database row? Is this part of what you're asking?) Thanks! - Your Friendly Neighborhood Mod

Comment: @cherrykoda This is something unrelated to Commerce products. It could just as well be notes or addresses. I went the easy route by rendering a new line of form elements for each product with JS and I store all data in a single hidden field as JSON. I should probably have created another DB table and used references but that would have made the whole thing more complex without the need for it.